# How to link Stripe session with my own web app session

Tags: express, stripe-payments, session-variables

I have the following setup: a very simple web app written with Node & Express.
There is a simple index.html page that only contains a Stripe Payment link, as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stripe Payment Link</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Stripe Payment Link</p>
    <a href="https://buy.stripe.com/test_28oaGrdLl3q28jCbII">buy</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Stripe dashboard I have setup the payment link to redirect to a success page, once the payment is completed.
The success page is very simple and it has a div element where I try to display the email of the customer who made the purchase:

```
<div id="paymentDetails">
        <p>
            <%= customerEmail %>
        </p>
</div
```

In the main Node file - app.js (the one that starts the app) I have the followings:

1. a default route (/) to the index.html page. When the user clicks the Stripe link, he is directed to the Stripe checkout page where he can enter the credit card details.
2. I have a Stripe webhook (on route /webhook) )where I listen for payment events. When the payment is successfully completed, I capture the customer email address from the Stripe event.
3. A route for the /success page where I try to pass the customer email (but it does not work).

What I want to achieve is the following: once I capture the customer email address from the Stripe webhook event, I want to somehow pass this customer email address to the success page.
I tried to add the email address as a session variable, but I realized that the Stripe webhook where I get the email address has a different session from my web application session, hence this is not working.

Any advice is more than welcome, thank you very much!

-- The code for ap.js below:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_');
// This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
const endpointSecret = "whsec_";
// Use body-parser to retrieve the raw body as a buffer
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./key-cert.pem')
    };
// ---------------------------------------------
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

// Middleware for session management
app.use(session({
    secret: 'kjdakadkdakdakdakldakldadakl',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

// static files are stored in public folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Default route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Entering default route....session id = ' + req.sessionID);
    // Send the index.html file
    //req.session.var1= 'this is var 1 stored in session';
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/index.html'));
});

app.get('/sess', (req, res) => {
    console.log('enter session route...sessionID = ' + req.sessionID);
    // Render the success.ejs page and pass the email as a parameter
    var var1 = req.session.var1;
    if (var1) {
        console.log('we found var1 '+ var1);
    }
    else {
        console.log('There is no var1 stored in session....');
    }
    res.render('session', {var1: var1}) ;
});

// Define a route for handling successful payment redirection
app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
    console.log('enter success route...')
    // Render the success.ejs page and pass the email as a parameter
    var emailVar = req.session.customerEmail;
    console.log('Reading data from session: ' + req.sessionID);
    if (emailVar) {
        console.log('we found email '+ emailVar);
    }
    else {
        console.log('There is no customer email stored in session....');
    }
    res.render('success', {customerEmail: emailVar}) ;
});

// Stripe webhook route where Stripe will send notifications about the payment status
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (req, res) => {
    console.log('Entering Stripe webhook....')
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

    let event;
    let customerEmail;

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, endpointSecret);
        //event = request.body;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Entering error....' + err);
        response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
    }
    console.log('Event type is ' + event.type);

    const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
    console.log("we obtained the Event Data...id = " + paymentIntent.id + ', object type = ' + paymentIntent.object);        
  // Handle the event
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            console.log('Payment is successfull says Stripe webhook....');
            console.log('Amount paid by customer is: ' + paymentIntent.amount_received);
            // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
            break;
        case 'payment_intent.created':
            console.log('Payment intent created....');
            break;
        case 'charge.succeeded':
            customerEmail = paymentIntent.billing_details.email;
            console.log('Charge succedeed says Stripe webhook....');
            console.log('Email address of customer is: ' + customerEmail);
            //response.redirect('/success.html?email=${customerEmail}');
            // Store the customer email in the session
            if (req.session.customerEmail) {
                console.log('Webhook: there is an customerEmail in the session');
            }
            else {
                console.log('Webhook: there is NO customerEmail in the session');
                req.session.customerEmail = customerEmail;
                console.log('webhook: check if we can retrieve the customerEmail from session: ' + req.sessionID + '....'+ req.session.customerEmail);
            }
            break;
        case 'checkout.session.completed':
            console.log('Checkout session completed says Stripe webhook....');
            break;
        // ... handle other event types
        default:
            console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
    }

    // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
    res.send();
});

// custom 404 page
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.type('text/plain')
    res.status(404)
    res.send('404 - Not Found')
})

// custom 500 page
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.message)
    res.type('text/plain')
    res.status(500)
    res.send('500 - Server Error')
})

// Create a NodeJS HTTPS listener on port 4000 that points to the Express app
// Use a callback function to tell when the server is created.
/*https
  .createServer(options, app)
  .listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('server is running at port 3000')
  });*/

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express started on http://localhost:${port}; ` + `press Ctrl-C to terminate.`))
```

Comment: For email address entering in the Checkout Session, it can be found [`customer_details.email`](https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_details-email). Webhook event is sent to a separate endpoint asynchronously that doesn't share the same session as the web application. One way is to save the email address in your own database, and your frontend will retry pulling the email address from database until it exists.

Comment: Hello,  This is exactly how I do it at the moment , I retrieve the email address from the Stripe webhook ....but given that the Stripe webhook comes with its own web session, I cannot see how would I be able to pass the the email to my success page.